# pdf.js:"pdf.js throwing Null response for external pdf URL."

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, pdf.js

I am using pdf.js to render pdf files on browser. It's working fine when I give a file which is located in root folder, but when I give any external URL it throws null response.
Here is error.

> PDF.js v? (build: ?)
>    Message: Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "http://nodetuts.com/pdf/handson-nodejs-sample.pdf".

your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary that the pdf file must be on same server ?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-xhr